# floating bar javascript (prototype or scriptaculous)

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, scriptaculous

I'm looking for a horizontal bar that scrolls with the page, ideally implemented in prototype or scriptaculous. I want it to be exactly like the bar shown to first time usersof stackoverflow telling them about the FAQs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

position:fixed

see also: [Simulating position: fixed in IE6 with a div of 100% height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387485/simulating-position-fixed-in-ie6-with-a-div-of-100-height)